# Php count cannot work for my notification

Tags: php, mysqli

When I echo `''.$count.''` its display `11101101`. But I want to total count like 8 or 7 etc. What is my wrong here in my code please.

I used to try `$count = mysqli_num_rows($u);` also but result was same.

my code:

```
    $g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM update WHERE from_id`='".$b."' OR `to_id`='".$session->id."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
    $ids[]= $rows['id'];
}   
foreach ( $ids as $id ){
    $u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM updateside WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '0'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $count = mysqli_affected_rows($dbh);
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($u)) {
    $nid= $rows['id'];
} 

echo ''.$count.'';

}
```

Comment: Where is the `$dbh` ?

Comment: The $dbh is irrelevant, at the moment he is echo'ing the $count within the foreach statement, so each id is echo'ing a $count. Please see my answer on part two, this will do exactly what you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign total count to a variable something like this:

Assumes mysqli_num_rows needs query result `$u` as argument.

```
$total = 0;    

foreach ( $ids as $id ){
    $u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM updateside WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '0'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($u);
    $count = ($count == "") ? 0 : $count;
    $total = $total + $count;
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($u)) {
        $nid= $rows['id'];
    }
} 

echo $total;
```

Comment: Its display now 123445667

Comment: @koc the final $total should be outside the while and foreach loop. You have to note the closing braces

Comment: Thank u sir, its working now. Please explain me $count = ($count == "") ? 0 : $count;

Comment: @koc its an extra condition, checking whether $count is null. Incase null $count =0 otherwise the value of $count. FYI Ternery operator: http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change your code a bit like this

```
foreach ( $ids as $id ){
    $u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM updateside WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '0'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($u)) {
        $nid= $rows['id'];
    }
    echo mysqli_num_rows($u);
}
```

If you need to echo after all foreach statements use this

```
$count=0;
foreach ( $ids as $id ){
    $u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM updateside WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '0'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($u)) {
        $nid= $rows['id'];
    }
    $count = $count + mysqli_num_rows($u);
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: second solution i showed here should work fine, the first one is more of a cleanup solution but noticed you needed to count around each array item.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use

```
$count=$u->num_rows;

echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is simply formatting bug. Why use the `''` here?
Try simply write:

```
echo $count;
```

Comment: Thank u but no change sir